# Corecursion Doesn't Terminate After Small Change

Tags: racket, fractals, corecursion

I wrote a function in Racket to produce something similar to the following fractal.

[image: Circle Fractal]

```
(define CUT-OFF 5)
(define CIRCLE-MODE "outline")

(define (circle-fractal size colour)
  (local [(define full-circle (circle size CIRCLE-MODE colour))]

    (cond [(<= size CUT-OFF) full-circle]
          [else
           (overlay/align "middle" "middle" 
                          full-circle
                          (beside (circle-fractal (/ size 2) colour)
                                  (circle-fractal (/ size 2) colour)))])))
```

It passes my tests.

I changed the code, thinking the below would be more readable.

```
(define (circle-fractal size colour)
  (local [(define full-circle (circle size CIRCLE-MODE colour))
          (define half-circle (circle-fractal (/ size 2) colour))]

    (cond [(<= size CUT-OFF) full-circle]
          [else
           (overlay/align "middle" "middle" 
                          full-circle
                          (beside half-circle half-circle))])))
```

Now the function doesn't terminate. Racket reaches its memory limit with no output.

Does each corecursive call somehow not approach the trivial case after this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version `(circle-fractal (/ size 2) colour)` is evaluated only if `size > CUT-OFF`. In the second it's called regardless of size. This way you lost your recursion base case.

Try:

```scm
(define (circle-fractal size colour)
  (define full-circle (circle size CIRCLE-MODE colour))
  (cond [(<= size CUT-OFF) full-circle]
        [else
         (define half-circle (circle-fractal (/ size 2) colour))
         (overlay/align "middle" "middle" 
                        full-circle
                        (beside half-circle half-circle))]))
```

Comment: Note: if you're using a teaching language, add `local` as you did (and remember specifying *which one* in your future questions). In full Racket `local` is never used afaik.

Comment: Thank you! I am using the teaching language. I'll remember to specify next time. It's also `size <= CUT-OFF` just to clarify to other readers. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the condition... your code is in the `else` clause, so it's evaluated when the *opposite* of `size <= CUT-OFF` is true. Hence it's evaluated when `size > CUT-OFF`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thank you!